# Bayesian inference of stochastically evolving model parameters

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian, machine-learning, bayesian-probability, data-analysis

I have a question related to self-calibration in radio interferometry, but I will try to phrase it as generic as possible. I have a set of data points, $D = \{ d_{0, t_0}, d_{1, t_0}, ..., d_{M, t_0}, d_{0, t_1}, d_{1, t_1}, ..., d_{M, t_1}, ..., d_{0, t_n}, d_{1, t_n}, ... d_{M, t_n} \}$, taken at different time intervals, $t = 0, 1, ..., n$ to which I want to fit a model. For each time interval I have $N$ model parameters $\theta = \{\theta_{0, t_0}, \theta_{1, t_0}, ..., \theta_{N, t_0} \}$ and $M = N ( N - 1 ) / 2$ data points.

[image]

I have generated some noisy simulated data from my model so that the model parameters evolve with time in a stochastic manner (which is close to real observations; see Figure 1 for the evolution of my simulated model parameters) and my aim is to infer those parameters. Due to SNR restrictions, I can not infer the model parameters in every single time interval, so instead what I am doing is to group together data points taken e.g. at 5 consecutive time intervals and minimise the likelihood of my model given the data to find the average $\bar{\theta}_{k, t^{'}_0}$, $(k = 0, 1, ..., N)$ for $t_0< t < t_5$ and so on. In this way I infer the average set of $N$ model parameters for each binned up subset of my data, independently (seems to be working fine).

However, my approach does not take advantage of the fact that the evolution of the model parameters is a stochastic process, which means $\theta_{k, t_{n+1}}$ is not independent from $\theta_{k, t_{n}}$. I am wondering if I can solve for all the model parameters simultaneously and introduce Gaussian priors so that the prior for the k'th model parameter at $t_n$ is centered at $\theta_{k, t_{n - 1}}$. In this case would the expression to minimize look something like this,
\begin{equation} \label{eq:self_calibration}
    P({\theta} | d) = \prod_{n=0} \left( L(d_n | {\theta_n}) \prod_{k=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{\frac{(\theta_{k, t_n} - \theta_{k, t_{n-1}})^2}{\sigma^2}} \right)
\end{equation}
where $d_n = \{ d_{0, t_n}, d_{1, t_n}, ... d_{M, t_n} \}$, $\theta_n = \{\theta_{0, t_n}, \theta_{1, t_n}, ..., \theta_{N, t_n} \}$ and $\sigma$ will be fixed to some value. Does my problem fall into a particular category of bayesian statistics problems, so I can read up more about this?

Comment: Have you tried asking at CrossValidated [https://stats.stackexchange.com/]?